# How to insert input into Jupyter notebook using WebExecute

Tags: web-access, html, webservices, jupyter-notebook

I started web session and opened a Jupyter notebook in it:

```
session = StartWebSession["Chrome", Visible -> True]
WebExecute[session,{"OpenPage"->"http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb"}]
```

In Chrome I had to input Token authentication to get to the notebook. Chrome looked like this then:

[image]

Then I execute the following code in Mathematica to find all `textarea` tags. It found three such tags as can be seen also on image above (three `In`).

```
textarea=WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "textarea"]
```

Then I wanted to insert different input to the first input cell in which we can see `7+6` on the image.

So I execute the following code in hoping it replaces `7+6` with `3*7`:

```
WebExecute[session,"TypeElement"->{textarea[[1]],"3*7"}]
```

But I got error:

[image]

**Why it does not work? How to insert text inside input cell of Jupyter notebook using WebExecute?**

The HTML of `textarea` tag looked liked this:

```
<textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; bottom: -1em; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;"></textarea>
```